# C#: Pass additional argument to delegate by reference

Tags: c#, optimization, delegates, pass-by-reference

I am currently trying to heavily optimize the runtime of a program and stumbled across the following problem.

**Problem**

At some point I have to call `EnumWindows` from the `user32.dll` (see [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-enumwindows)), definition looks like this:

```cs
internal static class NativeMethods
{
    public delegate bool EnumWindowsProc(IntPtr hWnd, int lParam);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    public static extern bool EnumWindows(EnumWindowsProc enumFunc, IntPtr lParam);
    //...
}
```

As you can see I pass a delegate to do something with each window.

I call this method like this:

```cs
NativeMethods.EnumWindows(GetVisibleWindowDelegate, IntPtr.Zero);
```

with

```cs
private bool GetVisibleWindowDelegate(IntPtr windowHandle, int _)
```

Note: I don't use the `int` parameter in the delegate, thus the name.

This works just fine. Now for the optimization: I have to access and store several dynamic lists of types  `List<IntPtr>` and `IDictionary<int, Rectangle>` wrapped in an object called `RuntimeInformation` across multiple methods in various classes.

Copying the values back and forth from this RuntimeInformation object uses precious runtime of about 20ms on my hardware for each method call. That's why I want to pass this object by reference instead, but I fail to get the reference into my `GetVisibleWindowDelegate`.

**Approach**

I can not change the delegate-type because I have no control over calling it.

If I try calling the `EnumWindows` like this:

```cs
NativeMethods.EnumWindows(
    (windowHandle, _) => GetVisibleWindowDelegate(windowHandle, ref runtimeInformation),
    IntPtr.Zero
);
```

I get the error

```
Error CS1628  Cannot use ref, out, or in parameter 'runtimeInformation' inside an anonymous method, lambda expression, query expression, or local function
```

A class property for references does not exist to my knowledge.

**Question**

How do I get a reference to my `RuntimeInformation` into the function I use as delegate? Are there alternatives to this approach?

The solution should have high performance (first priority) and be maintainable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`GCHandle`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.gchandle?view=netframework-4.8) for this. In fact the [docs for `GCHandle.Alloc`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.gchandle.alloc?view=netframework-4.8) have an example for exactly what you're trying to do.

```
private static bool GetVisibleWindowDelegate(IntPtr windowHandle, IntPtr lparam)
{
    var handle = GCHandle.FromIntPtr(lparam);
    var runtimeInformation = (RuntimeInformation)handle.Target;

    // ...
}


RuntimeInformation runtimeInformation = ...

var handle = GCHandle.Alloc(runtimeInformation);
try
{
    var callback = new EnumWindowsProc(GetVisibleWindowDelegate);
    NativeMethods.EnumWindows(callback, GCHandle.ToIntPtr(handle));
}
finally
{
    handle.Free();
}
```